# How to stop all scheudlers all at time in java play

Tags: java, scala, playframework, akka, scheduled-tasks

```
scheduledFeeds.forEach(scheduledFeed -> {
         actorSystem.scheduler().schedule(
                Duration.create(nextExecutionTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS), // initialDelay
                Duration.create(interval, timeUnit), // interval
                () -> runJob(tenant),
                this.executionContext )

       });
```

I need to stop all jobs at once
do I need to store all the cancellables and then cancel ?If ,yes then how to store and cancel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you schedule the task, store that object in a Collection so that they can be cancelled later if needed.

```java
Collection<Future<?>> futures = ...;

futures.add(actorSystem.scheduler().schedule(...));
```

To cancel

```
futures.forEach(future -> future.cancel(true));
```

There might be an exception there IIRC that might need to be caught.

Comment: Thanks Jason ,
1.but from which package I need to use Future (like "import play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.util.concurrent.Future;
"/"import akka.compat.Future;
") for both of this Its not working
--------------------------------------
2 .Collection<Future<?>> futures---> what does "?" mean .what I need to replace

Comment: No problem eh. Future is a part of the java.util.concurrent package. ? means wildcard, with no particular bound, meaning that it could be a Future object that returns essentially anything. In your case, runJob doesn't seem to return anything, but if it returned Integer for example, you would use Future<Integer>.

Comment: I tried with java.util.concurrent . I am getting the following error
"play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[incompatible types: akka.actor.Cancellable cannot be converted to java.util.concurrent.Future]"

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a collection of cancellables

    Collection<Cancellable> futures =new ArrayList<Cancellable>();

// store the cancellables which are returned from schedulers

    futures.add(actorSystem.scheduler().schedule(...));

//then iterate each cancellable and stop the scheduler

    for(Cancellable future:futures) {
            future.cancel();
            future=null;
                }
```